# Android - Uiautomatorviewer - How to view uiautomator dump view.xml file using Uiautomatorviewer?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I am planning to capture the uiautomator dump view.xml files and try to view using Uiautomatorviewer.

```
adb shell uiautomator dump view.xml
```

Is there a way to capture the uiautomatorsnapshots from command line while tests are running and able to view these files using Uiautomatorviewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `adb pull /sdcard/view.xml ./view.uix`
- Import it using `Open > UI xml dump`
- Take a screenshot: `adb exec-out screencap -p > screen.png`
- Import it using `Open > Screenshot`